# Batch command to run something when I close the program

Tags: batch-file

So I'm running a minecraft server for a few friends, and made a simple python script that automatically backups the server. I want this script to run whenever I enter "stop" in the terminal (which closes the server). The server is started with this batch file:

```
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

Is there anything I can add to it that will make it run a python script whenever it closes?

Answer (score 0):

This example may help.
"echo done" will be executed after I close the notepad.

```
@echo off
start /wait notepad
echo done
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path to your Python script into your .bat file

```
@echo off
C:/python_path/Python.exe C:/your_path/Your_file.py
pause
```

You can run a script from the batch file by typing the path of the Python executable, followed by the full path to the script. If your script takes parameters, do not forget to supply the required parameters as well.